# Spyder Editor: how to read csv file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, spyder

[image]

I am new to spyder editor. Usually, in python, we will read CSV file by pd.read_csv(path). Here the dataset variable is not created. I don't why it is not created. I checked the path also it correct only. I run the same code in jupyter notebook it was working there. I don't know why it not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a dataset variable but it's not visible in variable explorer.

Try updating the spyder to fix this.

Also, there is an option in the Variable Explorer called Exclude unsupported types that if unchecked will show all variable types on it.